# Last Entry that matches a condition per Window

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This dummy data represents a device with measurement cycles.
One measurement clycle goes from "Type" Init to Init.

What I want to find out is the f.e. last error (the condition will get way more complicated) within each measurement cylce.

I already figured out a solution for this. What I really want to know is if there is an easier / more efficient way to calculate this.

Example Dataset

```
val df_orig = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      ("Init", 1, 17, "I"),
      ("TypeA", 2, 17, "W"),
      ("TypeA", 3, 17, "E"),
      ("TypeA", 4, 17, "W"),
      ("TypeA", 5, 17, "E"),
      ("TypeA", 6, 17, "W"),
      ("Init", 7, 12, "I"),
      ("TypeB", 8, 12, "W"),
      ("TypeB", 9, 12, "E"),
      ("TypeB", 10, 12, "W"),
      ("TypeB", 11, 12, "W"),
      ("TypeB", 12, 12, "E"),
      ("TypeB", 13, 12, "E")
    )).toDF("Type", "rn", "X_ChannelC", "Error_Type")
```

The following code represents my solution.

```
val fillWindow = Window.partitionBy().orderBy($"rn").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

    //create window
    val df_with_window = df_orig.withColumn("window_flag", when($"Type".contains("Init"), 1).otherwise(null))
        .withColumn("window_filled", sum($"window_flag").over(fillWindow))

    val window = Window.partitionBy("window_filled").orderBy($"rn").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

    //calulate last entry
    val df_new = df_with_window.withColumn("is_relevant", when($"Error_Type".contains("E"), $"rn").otherwise(null))
      .withColumn("last", last($"is_relevant", true).over(window))
      .withColumn("pass", when($"last" === $"is_relevant", "Fail").otherwise(null))

    df_new.show()
```

Result:

```
+-----+---+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+----+--------+
| Type| rn|X_ChannelC|Error_Type|window_flag|window_filled|is_relevant|last|    pass|
+-----+---+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+----+--------+
| Init|  1|        17|         I|          1|            1|       null|   5|    null|
|TypeA|  2|        17|         W|       null|            1|       null|   5|    null|
|TypeA|  3|        17|         E|       null|            1|          3|   5|    null|
|TypeA|  4|        17|         W|       null|            1|       null|   5|    null|
|TypeA|  5|        17|         E|       null|            1|          5|   5|This one|
|TypeA|  6|        17|         W|       null|            1|       null|   5|    null|
| Init|  7|        12|         I|          1|            2|       null|  13|    null|
|TypeB|  8|        12|         W|       null|            2|       null|  13|    null|
|TypeB|  9|        12|         E|       null|            2|          9|  13|    null|
|TypeB| 10|        12|         W|       null|            2|       null|  13|    null|
|TypeB| 11|        12|         W|       null|            2|       null|  13|    null|
|TypeB| 12|        12|         E|       null|            2|         12|  13|    null|
|TypeB| 13|        12|         E|       null|            2|         13|  13|This one|
+-----+---+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+----+--------+
```

Comment: did my answer help you, if yes please accept it

Comment: It did not really help me since it is the same answer only with shorter code. The physical plan works the same way. Two window functions are used in both solutions

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that is more efficient (still 2 window functions used, but a bit shorter):

```
val df_new = df_orig
 .withColumn("measurement", sum(when($"Type"==="Init",1)).over(Window.orderBy($"rn")))
 .withColumn("pass", $"rn"===max(when($"Error_Type"==="E",$"rn")).over(Window.partitionBy($"measurement")))
 .show()

+-----+---+----------+----------+-----------+-----+
| Type| rn|X_ChannelC|Error_Type|measurement| pass|
+-----+---+----------+----------+-----------+-----+
| Init|  1|        17|         I|          1|false|
|TypeA|  2|        17|         W|          1|false|
|TypeA|  3|        17|         E|          1|false|
|TypeA|  4|        17|         W|          1|false|
|TypeA|  5|        17|         E|          1| true|
|TypeA|  6|        17|         W|          1|false|
| Init|  7|        12|         I|          2|false|
|TypeB|  8|        12|         W|          2|false|
|TypeB|  9|        12|         E|          2|false|
|TypeB| 10|        12|         W|          2|false|
|TypeB| 11|        12|         W|          2|false|
|TypeB| 12|        12|         E|          2|false|
|TypeB| 13|        12|         E|          2| true|
+-----+---+----------+----------+-----------+-----+
```